# BrowserLink VS2013 not connecting

Tags: browser-link

my issue is, BrowserLink never connects to my Browser in "Browser Link Dashboard"

- i'm using Visual Studio 2013 Prem Update 5 on a Win10 machine
- project is a MVC 5 application
- Browser is IE11.212.10586.0

BL is activated in the dropdown of the refreshbutton

From here, when i run my app on IISExpress, the BL Dashboard says no connection
but in the HTML i can find the script-Tags

[images, i'm not rated enaugh to implement in post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u77mn.png)

at least, i checked the web and found some web.config parts i should try, but that not resolved my issue

```
1# <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />

2# <add name="Browser Link for HTML" path="*.html" verb="*"
       type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       resourceType="File" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

so i need to change, save, refresh my page all the time - someone tipps for me what could be wrong?

Many thanks

**UPDATE 2016-06-23**

The TrafficFiddle by IE10 does not contain a GET Request with BL in URL

He does:

- Get HTML File
- Load scripts and stuff by "bundle.cs"
- load image

Additional: Some weired things happen with DOM Explorer.
There is only html>Head! no body is listed or BL scripts, when i use "inspect element" the full DOM do appear

[DOM displayed initial by browser - weired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrMjQ.png)

I would guess the browser would stop add stuff into DOM because of any script issue in head - but when i look with inspect at the "real DOM" there's just the body after the printed DOM - sry not enaugh rep to show a 3rd link :(

Comment: Is it possible there's a syntax error somewhere else in the page? If Browser Link's `<script>` tag is there, then the browser should at least try to fetch the script, unless it's not interpreting the tag correctly.

Comment: Also, does Browser Link work in any other browser besides IE?

Comment: Good Point, no it doesen't BUT!  Here is a request (Chrome) that status stays "failed" - i'm not that experienced with chrome... here's all i can see atm in deVTools: Request URL:http://localhost:50404/c80528e5d7964788818db5a9db8b2aed/browserLink with status failed - the application is hosted on http://localhost:1265/ (Port changing each time)... script says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking at a network trace in Fiddler or your browser tools. Since the script tag has been inserted, there should be two requests that have "browserLink" in the URL. The first one gets the Browser Link script, and the second one establishes the SignalR connection. If either of those is failing or missing, the failure could provide a hint why Browser Link is failing to connect.

Comment: Updated original post - thanks for idea, but doesent' help

Comment: As in main-post comments - i used another browser and found an error: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED... additional, the port of the call is unknown to me, i thought it's some magic from VS "localhost:50404" and my app is hosted on "1265"